# How can I hide background video on mobile and display an image?

Tags: html, css, video

On my page I have a background video

```
<video poster="video/p01-v01.jpg" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted">
    <source src="video/p01-v01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video/p01-v01.webm" type="video/webm">
    <img src="video/p01-v01.jpg">
</video>
```

I would like to hide them since on some iOs device is displayed video first frame with play button

I would like to display the image placeholder

I would prefer to do it via CSS and media query if is possible
I did try this way but it doesn't seem to work?

```
video > source {
    display: none;
}
```

Is the the only way to do it hide an image behind and show it on small screens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The visibility of the `<source>` tag has no impact on the visibility of the video itself. It is a just a tag to declare the possible sources of the `<video>` tag.

My best advice is to use a wrapper if you want to stick to CSS, or else other solutions could be done using javascript.

**NOTE:** you will have to set default display for the image to `none` outside of your media query / in tag style or it will show in addition to the video!

```css
.videoWrapper > video {
    display: none;
}
.videoWrapper > img {
    display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoWrapper">
    <video poster="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
        <source src="video/p01-v01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="video/p01-v01.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" style="display: none;">
</div>
```